# Notebook and terminal launch wrong python version

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub, jupyter-console

I don't know why but after half day using my kernel 'geomatic' in jupyterhub, something crash. My notebook doesn't work anymore... After some researches, I understand that issue comes from python version used by notebook or console. It's a bad one python: 3.6.3 whereas in my kernel terminal (source activate geomatic) I have python 3.6.6. I don't know why but this difference makes crash my scripts and I can't import geopandas in a notebook for example.

Answer (score 1):

always install from "Anaconda Prompt" if using Anaconda Navigator in windows. I had a similar issue and installing the package using Anaconda prompt. Make sure the python version from Anaconda prompt and jupyter are the same (should be)